# Android - Using a class to programatically changing layout size depending on screen size

Tags: android

so I've created a class to change a layout size programatically. The class is :

```
public class ActivityResize extends Activity{

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    //private Point size = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        Log.d("getMetrics", "Value : " + displayMetrics);
    }

    public int width(int sizeX)
    {
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * (sizeX/100);
        return screenWidth;
    }

    public int height(int sizeY)
    {
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels * (sizeY/100);
        return screenHeight;
    }
}
```

Am I doing the `DisplayMetrics` wrong? Because the log returns 0 whenever I try to log `screenWidth` or `screenHeight`.

Comment: It not depend on this. but you didn't added setContentView(layout)

Comment: It's a class which is only used for calculation, so it doesn't need a layout..

Answer (score 0):

you calculate the size using `displayMetrics.widthPixels * (sizeX/100);`,notice that if your sizeX<100,it will be 0,so the result will be 0,to fix it,you can change your `sizeX` type to `float` or use

```
displayMetrics.widthPixels * (sizeX/100.0f);
```

Comment: I ended up using `int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;` to reduce complication in other classes lol

Comment: you mean screenWidth by call `displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;` is 0? if so,please show us the sizeX value and `displayMetrics.widthPixels` value,I have tested that we can get correct value from `displayMetrics`.

Comment: `sizeX` value is 80 and everything in `displayMetrics` is 0.. When I call it from within the class itself, it shows the usual `DisplayMetrics{density=3.0, width=1080, height=1920, scaledDensity=3.0, xdpi=403.0, ydpi=403.0}` BUT when I call it from another class.. It all changed to 0 which defeats its purpose of being a class which can be called from another class to adjust the layouts inside

Comment: How you use it in your another class,I tested it it will be ok,please show use the code.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to find the answer which is to ONLY use the `ActivityResize` class (renamed to `LayoutResize` to lessen confusion) to calculate. It had an `onCreate` which made itself a class with `intent` if my memory serves me right. I changed the class to this :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;

public class LayoutResize extends Activity{

    public DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

    public int width(int sizeX, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
    {
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels * sizeX / 100;
        return screenWidth;
    }

    public int height(int sizeY, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics)
    {
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels * sizeY / 100;
        return screenHeight;
    }
}
```

So I removed the `onCreate` which has `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);` and added the `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);` in every other class I use this class from. And also declared `DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();` outside the `onCreate`.

I call the class from any other class using `layoutResize.height(100, displayMetrics);`